# DataLoader batch loading bug (MyBatis, JavaEE)

Tags: java, graphql, jax-rs, mybatis, java-ee-7

I have graphql in my production, and it's forbidden to share the code. I'm using graphql-java-servlet, as ORM I use MyBatis.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
     <artifactId>graphql-java-servlet</artifactId>
     <version>9.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After enabling BatchLoading I found that graphQL DataLoader confuses places of batch-requested Entities. Also it's easy to check if take a look at futureCacheMap, you will find that Key(Id) And Value(Entity) have different ids.

After debugging, I didn't find the way how graphQL resolves Entities after batchLoading (1000 psc). So I decided that I should have some ordering, so I implemented it, but it didn't resolve the issue.

For example:
I Have Parent.class which have Childs inside.

```
class Parent {
    private Long id;
    private List<Long> childsIds;
}
```

I have ChildDataloader

```
private BatchLoader<Long, Child> buildBatchLoader() {
    return list -> > CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> childService.findByIds(list));                
    }

private DataLoader<Long, Child> buildDataLoader(BatchLoader batchLoader) {
    DataLoaderOptions options = DataLoaderOptions.newOptions();
    options.setMaxBatchSize(1000);
    return new DataLoader<Long, Child>(batchLoader, options);
    }
}
```

I have ChildsFetcher where I call dataLoader.loadMany()

```
public class ChildsFetcher implements DataFetcher<CompletableFuture<List<Child>>>{

    private static final String PK_FIELD_NAME = "childsIds";

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<List<LoadDefinitionDTO>> get(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
        GraphQLContext context = environment.getContext();
        DataLoaderRegistry dataLoaderRegistry = context.getDataLoaderRegistry().orElseThrow(
                () -> new DalException("there was no dataLoaderRegistry in context", Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        );
        List<Long> childsIds = getParentFieldValue(environment, PK_FIELD_NAME , List.class);

        DataLoader<Long, Child> childDataLoader = dataLoaderRegistry.getDataLoader("childDataLoader");
        return childDataLoader.loadMany(childsIds)
    }
}
```

For Example I have 2 Parents with 3 child each.

```
parents: [
 {
   "id": 1
   "childIds": {1,3,5}
 },
 {
   "id": 2
   "childIds": {2,4,6}
 }
]
```

As a result in fetcher I will have 2 requests:

1. `childDataLoader.loadMany({1,3,5})`
2. `childDataLoader.loadMany({2,4,6})`

In Dataloader it will be only one (as expected), but look at the order of the ids (I cannot take control on it):

```
childService.findByIds({1,3,5,2,4,6})
```

And in output I will receive:

```
"data": {
    "parents": [
      { 
        "id": 1,
        "childs": [
          {
            "id": 1,
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
           },
          {
            "id": 3,
           }
       },
      { 
        "id": 2,
        "childs": [
          {
            "id": 4,
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
           },
          {
            "id": 6,
           }
       }
      ]
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Normally sorting results of childService#findByIds according to order of input-ids should be doing the trick. Are you sure that order of input-id list is already messed up? Did you verify with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, I verify it with a debugger, and sorting of sql responce is now helping

Comment: if I tried to do smt like this:
        `childService.findByIds(list).thenApply(listEntityes -> {
            long count = listEntityes.stream()
            .filter(entitye -> !listIds.contains(.(entitye .getId()))).count();
            if (count > 0) {
                throw new Exception("Different sql request and response");
            }
            return it;
        });`
I will get an Exception

Comment: If you set break point inside CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> childService.findByIds(list));, is order of list still correct?

Comment: in DataLoader.class, childService.findByIds(list) will be already batched and have order as I provide early -> {1,2,3,4,5,6}, but should have 1,3,5,2,4,6

Comment: Sorry, no idea then. I had similar problem and manual sorting of result entries solved it for me.

Comment: I think I found the solution, also I had some missed sort, which broken order for DataLoader. Will check and if it is, I will change my question and provide the answer

Answer (score 2):

Order of your answer have to be the same as order of the request,
If ORM have sorting the sql response, just resort it back in DataLoader after you get response from ORM, for example :

```
 private BatchLoader<Long, Child> buildBatchLoader() {
   return list -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
                   childService.findByIds(list).stream()
                     .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(entity -> 
                             list.indexOf(entity.getId())))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList()));
 };
```